# JavaScript regular expression to validate only path params in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to validate path params in the url for the below scenario.

I have a text box wr user will input path params and the text box should contain only path params as like below

> /{id}/{name}

I need to validate using regex expression whether the input contains forward slash with curly braces. if they are not then regex should fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
^(\/{(\w)+})+$/i
```

You could replace the `\w` with `[a-z0-9]` if you want to limit the params to alpha numeric values

```
^(\/{(\w)+})+\/?$/i
```

This will accept the trailing slash e.g. `/{id}/{name}/`

Comment: Dan thanks for your quick help. This one ^(\/{(\w)+})+$/i worked for me after appending forward slash in the beginning like /^(\/{(\w)+})+$/i. Is there any way to find duplicates in path /{id}/{name}/{id} using same regex

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know what characters you want to allow within `id` and `name`. This regex allows everything except `/` and `{`.

```
^\/{[^\/{]+?}\/{[^\/{]+?}$
```

And this one only allows `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_`, `-`:

```
^\/{[\w-]+?}\/{[\w-]+?}$
```

Comment: I want to allow characters, numbers,/ and {}. Other special characters should be restricted